# How to configure mercure connection subscription counts?

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose, mercure

I am using eventSource for subscription

```
 const eventSource = new EventSource(url);
        eventSource.onmessage = event => { console.log('publishEventFromTopic');}
```

After 6th connection (new tab in the browser), the connection to the server starts to be pending, cant subscribe to the event. How I can configure this, Mercure works in the docker container

Comment: You must run your apach2/nginx virtual host over HTTP/2 protocol at least, AND your Reverse proxy rule. Over HTTP/1 Mercure allow only 6 connections (browser tabs).

Comment: @Francisco how could I easily do it on docker?

Comment: Hi, i don't use Docker but, the idea is to configure your dockerized webserver or virtual host for use http2